# Regex decimal for negative number with formatting conditions

Tags: regex, decimal, negative-number

Dear gods of regex (http://xkcd.com/208/),

Please provide a pattern that matches decimal numbers up to 4 decimal places (I've included acceptable examples below) albeit with a couple extra conditions (listed at the bottom).

Acceptable:

```
0
0.1
0.12
0.123
0.1234
1
1.1
...
123456789.1234
```

(Note: the last example above is to indicate that there's no limit on how *big* the number can get)

Also acceptable are negative numbers:

```
-0.1
-0.12
-0.123
-0.1234
-1
-1.1
...
-123456789.1234
```

(Note: there's no limit on how *small* the negative number can get)

The following numbers, however, are **not acceptable**, namely: stand-alone minus / plus sign, negative zero, numbers with one or more leading zeros, numbers with a leading plus sign, and incomplete decimals, for example:

```
-
+
-0
0123456789.1234
007
+0.1
+123456789.1234
.1234
1.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: God of regex wants to see your attempts first, or it'll burn your digits.

Comment: @MarounMaroun wait till Wiktor comes :P

Comment: Pro-tip don't use a regex, in almost any language you're using there is a better solution.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, this humble servant uses his now digit-less stump of a hand to point out all the other SO posts on regex decimals that he's tried without any luck. Humble servant also offers to do god's sh*t work. Scan, crack copyrights, whatever they want. #acidburn

Comment: This Question is an example of how to write a good regexp question -- good list of what should match _and_ a good list of what should not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it: `^(-?0\.\d{1,4}|-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,4})?|0)$`. Here you can play around: https://regex101.com/r/e7ch1G/3

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex like this, but this will match few of the examples you don't want:

```
^-?\d+(?:.\d{1,4})?$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/O55Zbn/1)**

However, if you want a more complex regex to discard all the patterns you listed, then you could use the discard technique like this:

```
^-0$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^-?0\d+(?:\.\d+)?$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^-?\d+(?:.\d{1,4})?$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/O55Zbn/3)**

This kind of regex are supported by PCRE engines. So, if you are not using PCRE, you could achieve the same goal with capturing groups, so capturing groups capture the content you want, for instance:

```
^-0$|^-?0\d+(?:\.\d+)?$|^(-?\d+(?:.\d{1,4})?)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/O55Zbn/2)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
^(?:-|\+)?\d+?(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: `+` is a quantifier unless escaped or in a character class.

Comment: Ah I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`^(-?((0|[1-9]+)\.\d{1,4}|[1-9])|0)$`

https://regex101.com/r/xla5Wp/1